# How can I get Thymeleaf to work with Hyperscript dynamically?

Tags: thymeleaf, htmx, spring-thymeleaf, hyperscript

I have a section of HTML that is being generated by a collection using Thymeleaf.

I can iterate over the collection just fine but the issue is when I try and get Hyperscript to see the Thymeleaf variables.

For example:

```
        <card-form class="hidden" th:id="'new-card-form-' + ${board.id}">
            <form action="#" class="flex flex-col gap-2">
                <textarea class="textarea" placeholder="Enter title..."></textarea>
                <div class="w-full">
                    <button class="bg-sky-700 px-2 py-1 rounded-lg font-bold hover:bg-sky-600 active:scale-95"
                            hx-post="/boards">Save Card</button>
                    <button class="bg-gray-600 px-2 py-1 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-700 active:scale-95"
                            _="on click hide #new-card-form-${board.id} then show #board-footer-${board.id}">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </card-form>
```

Notice that I generate a custom "card-form" element with an id of `th:id="'new-card-form-' + ${board.id}"`  This works as expected.  The `board.id` is a UUID that gets passed along from the outer collection.

The issue is I don't know how to get Hypertext to recognize this ID.

The Hypertext code is:

```
_="on click hide #new-card-form-${board.id} then show #board-footer-${board.id}"
```

The "${board.id}" is being interpreted as a literal string.

How can I get Thymeleaf to inject that ID the way I expect?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try with `th:_="|on click hide #new-card-form-${board.id} then show #board-footer-${board.id}|"` ?

Comment: That worked!  I knew it would be something simple I was missing.  If you want to post an answer I will accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
th:_="|on click hide #new-card-form-${board.id} then show #board-footer-${board.id}|"
```

Thymeleaf allows to use `th:` prefix even for things it does not know and it will still process the attribute correctly. If you combine it with the correct [string concatenation](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/01/11/string-concatenation-with-thymeleaf/) then it should work.